# Locating text within a .csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, search

Within a .csv document I have is the line:

```
AAPL,"Apple Inc.","163.03","$827.22B","1980","Technology","Computer Manufacturing","https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl",
```

After beginning my program it prompts the user for the .csv filepath as well as the stock ticker to search for. In this instance I am searching for AAPL.

```
import csv
from tkinter import
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Stock locator")
w.pack()

nasdaqDatabase = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("NASDAQ Database", "Please input your NASDAQ database csv directory") 
webUrlTest = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Stock Ticker Input", "Input a stock ticker") 

with open(nasdaqDatabase, "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csvreader:
        if webUrlTest in row[0]:
            print(webUrlTest + ' has been located in the NASDAQ')
        else:
            print('not found')
            quit()
```

The output when the code is run searching for AAPL is the following:

```
not found

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why would it not return that AAPL has been found? Where am I going wrong in this example? Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Is AAPL your first stock ticker? If it isn't, you're going to read the first row, then quit. If it is, are you sure `webUrlTest` is `AAPL`?

Comment: @skam the line I am searching for is in column A row 201. It is deep within a list on the .csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for row in csvreader:
    if webUrlTest in row[0]:
        print(webUrlTest + ' has been located in the NASDAQ')
    else:
        print('not found')
        quit()
```

This will check the first row, and `quit()` if it's not what you're looking for.  Surely you want something more like this:

```
found = False
for row in csvreader:
    if webUrlTest in row[0]:
        print(webUrlTest + ' has been located in the NASDAQ')
        found = True
if not found:
    print('not found')
    quit()
```

You could also wrap it in a function to avoid the slightly kludgey `found` flag ;)

Comment: this is outputting that found = false NameError: name 'false is not defined

Comment: Apologies, forgot that Python uses `False`/`True` instead of `false`/`true`

Comment: Worked great. thanks! didn't realize that due to my quit() existing it would simply stop after one row. Silly mistake on my part. Part of learning right!

Answer (score 0):

You code quits if any row is not AAPL. What you intented to express with the `else` statement is

```
for row in csvreader:
    if webUrlTest in row[0]:
        print(webUrlTest + ' has been located in the NASDAQ')
        break
else:
    print('not found')
```

Some people have strong objections to `for ... else` statements. They would suggest this approach

```
found = False
for row in csvreader:
    if webUrlTest in row[0]:
        print(webUrlTest + ' has been located in the NASDAQ')
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print('not found')
```

For catching this kind of error by yourself, I would strongly recommend using a python *debugger*, so you can step through and watch the execution. There's a [built in debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), also most IDEs (eg PyCharm) have debuggers with nice interfaces. You can search for tutorials on how to use a debugger.